# How to call a change event on a condition

Tags: jquery

On click of a button, I am doing an Ajax call as shown below.

```
$(document).on('click', '#savenewcategoryforT2', function(event ) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urllocal + '/OMS/oms/categorylevelupdateservice',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(response) {
      var res = response;
      if (res == true) {

      }
    },
    error: function(e) {

    }
  });
});
```

Once the `success` `function` is triggered, is it possible to call the code below?

```
$(document).on('change', '#T1Select', function(event) {

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use a referenced function?

Comment: @A.Wolff Post that as an answer and i'll upvote.

Comment: Are looking to trigger an event or set up an event listener? If your intention is to set up an event listener (as suggested by the code), you don't need to wait for ajax success to set this up. As you know the event handler only fires if the event it is attached to occurs. **PLEASE CLARIFY**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger both your handler and browser native handler or [jQuery.triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to trigger only your handler

```
$('#T1Select').trigger('change');
```

Comment: `triggerHandler()` won't work for delegated event as not doing it bubbles: `Events triggered with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `#T1Select` in the DOM, you can just trigger the event:

```
$('#T1Select').change()
```